# Setting backspace=2 in zsh with vi bindings

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, vi-mode

I just set my `zsh` to vi mode as I feel the word/WORD (`w`/`b` `W`/`B`) skip keybindings will help me work faster than plain `^a` `^e` in emacs binding mode. However, I'd like to `set backspace=2` or `set backspace=eol, start`; I have this in my `.nvimrc`, and it's what I'm used to right now.

Is there any way to set this variable in `zsh`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind the backspace key to `backward-delete-char` instead of `vi-backward-delete-char`.

```
bindkey -v '^?' backward-delete-char
```

You may want to bind other `vi-*` [widgets](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Standard-Widgets) to their non-`vi-` variant. Run `bindkey -LM viins` to list the insert mode keymap in a form you can tweak and copy to your `.zshrc`.

Alternatively, if the word motion commands are all that drives you to the vi map, you can map them in Emacs mode.

```
bindkey '^[B' vi-backward-blank-word
bindkey '^[E' vi-forward-blank-word-end
bindkey '^[F' vi-forward-blank-word
bindkey '^[b' vi-backward-word
bindkey '^[e' vi-forward-word-end
bindkey '^[f' vi-backward-blank-word
```