# Backspace in zsh stuck

Tags: zsh, zle

In `set -o vi` mode in bash, when I press `Esc+k` to get the last entered command, and then `A`, I end up in the insert mode, which allows me to press `backspace` to start deleting the end of the last command.

With `zsh` in `set -o vi` mode, everything works up until the backspace part.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is much the same ground as http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206853/ .

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The quick answer, put this in your `~/.zshrc`:

```
bindkey -v '^?' backward-delete-char
```

Normally `'^?'` (backspace) is bound to `vi-backward-delete-char`, which is supposed to have the behavior you observe, as that is how `vi` (not `vim`, unless in vi classic mode) behaves.

Comment: Hmm... `vim` does not allow erasing characters to the left after pressing `A` regardless of compatibility mode.

Comment: @Kusalananda All of the vims I've used do.

Comment: We live in different worlds  ;-)

Comment: Note: `busybox`'s `vi` departs from this traditional behavior and lets you delete characters to the left just fine after anything that puts you into insert mode, including `A`. (So I never knew about this old traditional vi behavior.)

Comment: In vim (and neovim) this is configurable behavior, controlled by the `'backspace'` option, when it includes `start`.  See `:h 'backspace'` for details. neovim includes `start` in its defaults, but vim does not.